# ALSA/Pulse connect to microphone alias for remapping channels

Tags: linux, microphone, alsa, pulse-audio

I'm using Manjaro Linux, and I have a mono USB microphone that ALSA treats as stereo (It identifies it as a Q1U dynamic microphone, but it is a different mic that clearly uses the same DAC), with the signal going mostly to the Left channel, with a strange muted copy going to the right.

I am trying to get the signal fed to both stereo channels so that applications using PulseAudio don't get all the input on one side.

I've tried using PulseAudio's module-remap-source to convert the microphone to mono as per [ArchWiki's advice](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Microphone), adding this to `etc\pulse\default.pa`:

```
load-module module-remap-source master=alsa_card.usb-USB_Microphone_USB_Microphone-00 master_channel_map=front-left,front-right channel_map=mono,mono
```

And I spent hours trying various different options for the master_channel_map and channel_map settings, the only effect I could achieve was to swap the sound from left to right.

I have some setting in my /etc/asound.conf that I believe are creating an alias of my USB mic that should map the left channel to both sides:

```
pcm_slave.monomic{
    pcm "hw:2,0"
}

pcm.stereo-mic {
    type route
    slave monomic
    ttable {
        0.0 1    # in-channel 0, out-channel 0, 100% volume
        0.1 1    # in-channel 0, out-channel 1, 100% volume
    }
}

ctl.stereo-mic {
    type hw
    card 2
}
```

But now I'm stuck. If I use the `enter device name...` option in alsamixer and type in "stereo-mic", it shows me a capture mixer, but `arecord -l` doesn't list it, and I can't connect to it with pactl:

```
$ pactl load-module module-alsa-source stereo-mic
Failure: Module initialization failed
```

Are there any PulseAudio/ALSA experts out there that can help? There's some step that I'm missing, but it's really hard to find good accessible information on ALSA sources.